# How to imitate kwargs from Python in Typescript

Tags: python, typescript, oop

So I am building a small library in typescript. There is one base class from which multiple classes will inherit. The `base` class has many attribute that can be passed in constructor as parameters, which can have defaut values. The question is, if it is a must to provide those `base` class properties in constructor in every subclass?

Example:

```
class BaseClass {
    constructor(a: number, b: number, c: number, d: number) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }
    private a: number;
    private b: number;
    private c: number;
    private d: number;
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    constructor(a: number, b: number, c: number, d: number, e: number, f: number) {
        super(a, b, c, d);
        this.e = e;
        this.f = f;
    }
    private e: number;
    private f: number;
}
```

Are there any methods to reduce the verbosity, like python can use `kwargs` when calling super in `__init__`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass objects that work in a similar manner to kwargs. I have seen a similar coding style in aws CDK and  modern ecmascript standard(and consecutively typescript) seems to play well with that approach since object destructuring is a first class citizen long now.
For example:

```js
    interface BaseClassKwargs{
      a: number;
      b: number;
      c: number;
      d: number;
    }
    interface SubClassKwargs extends BaseClassKwargs{
      e: number;
      f: number;
    }
    class BaseClass {
        constructor(kwargs:BaseClassKwargs) {
            this.a = kwargs['a'];
            this.b = kwargs['b'];
            this.c = kwargs['c'];
            this.d = kwargs['d'];
        }
        private a: number;
        private b: number;
        private c: number;
        private d: number;
    }
    class SubClass extends BaseClass {
        constructor(kwargs:SubClassKwargs) {
            super(kwargs);
            this.e = kwargs['e'];
            this.f = kwargs['f'];
        }
        private e: number;
        private f: number;
    }
```

and taking advantage of restructuring can even be written as:

```js
    class BaseClass {
        constructor({a, b, c, d}:BaseClassKwargs) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
            this.d = d;
        }
        private a: number;
        private b: number;
        private c: number;
        private d: number;
    }
    class SubClass extends BaseClass {
        constructor({e,f, ...kwargs}:SubClassKwargs) {
            super(kwargs);
            this.e = e;
            this.f = f;
        }
        private e: number;
        private f: number;
    }
```

In aws cdk they are not called kwargs, they are called props but regardless of the name the mindset is similar.

Note that for having default values even the extreme case of having both the full object and its properties with defaults can be covered:

```
constructor({ a = 1, b = 0, c = -1, d = -2 } = {}): void {
  // ...
}
```

[Sample project with similar coding style](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ecs.Cluster.html)

[Typescript docs on destructuring](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#object-destructuring)